# How to store a large number of javascript objects in a db via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a front-end developer. I built a very-ajaxy-feeling jquery web app that can be used to record various statistics. It basically just gets user input, does a few very simple calculations and then writes them to the dom (via jquery's .html ).

I want to be able to save the changes that the user makes. Currently, if the page is refreshed, the dom goes back to its original state and the info entered and calculated is gone.

So I need to store this info (basically javascript objects of the sort playerOne.points = 12, playerOne.steals = 2, etc...) via ajax calls to the server. I don't know backend dev very well at all.

I think using PHP and MySQL will be the easiest solution. How would this be structured. What is the best way to pass that info back and forth and how does it get stored.

Can you just pass the dom itself, or portions of it, to a db and store it? And then retrieve it back if need be? Is that possible or just weird?

Any pointers in a good direction are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: UPDATE: The data needs to be stored in such a way that it can be accessed by other machines and at other times. So local storage and/or  cookies wouldn't be sufficient. I was unclear about this in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing that matters is that the data is saved between page refreshes, wouldn't it be easier to just use cookies and store all the data locally? That saves you the trouble of having user accounts and authentication and a database.

Comment: Interesting idea: more modern browsers also have other methods of storage (e.g. LocalStorage and WebSQL). There are several downsides in terms of data longevity, accessibility, and security... but there are also upsides so, it depends. Cookies always have to be round-tripped, but it *is* one form of storage... +1

Comment: This is a very good point. I should have been more clear and I will update my original question. I do need to store the data in such a way that it can be accessed from other machines and at other times. So local storage and/or cookies wouldn't be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely consider [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) if your server setup supports it. It's a database based on JSON, so great for storing JSON objects, right?